# How to preserve variable type when posting to php from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

When I use ajax to post data from Javascript to PHP, the php $_POST variables are always strings. Is there any way to preserve the variable type when posting. EG when posting a boolean true I want a boolean true and not a string 'true'.

Comment: The query string is going to be a string. You'll have to cast it in PHP or convert it yourself.

Comment: To convert the string "true" to boolean value true just ```$val = $_POST['boolflag'] == "true"``` there you have :-)

Comment: Collect all of your data in an object, then stringify that object to a JSON string. Post that JSON string to the server and let PHP decode it (json_decode). That should preserve your types...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JSON as format and the PHP json parser will do it for you.

You can find an example here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#90790

Comment: Thanks. Should just point out that JSON.stringify should be used rather than .toSource() - which also necessitates the deletion of the php line that removes the outer parenthesis.  The only downside is that it doesn't differentiate between objects and arrays, so json { a : ['b', 'c']} is indistinguishable from { a : { '0' : 'a', '1' : 'b'}}

Answer (score 3):

Not possible directly: values will always be initially read as strings on the PHP side.

If you need to coerce the values into other types and cannot hardcode these types in your code you will need to arrange for "type information" to be passed to PHP (also as a string). That's how protocols that inherently provide data type support, such as SOAP, work.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you can let the JSON parser be do it for you.
You can also try it by yourself by checking the values.

Like boolean: is_bool
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-bool.php

Like int: is_int
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

etc.

This can be done when you have the POST values, and check for example the number field if it is a int:

```
<?php
  $numberIsInt = is_int($_POST["number"]);
  if($numberIsInt) { 
    //Do something
  } else {
    //Return error or do something else
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ok you are right, i readed the question not good enough, however getting a -1 for this isnt correct too. You can check the values when you get a AJAX call (or normal call)

Comment: I will change my answer ;-) Make it more clear, then we have a deal :p

Comment: The reason I need to do this is so that I can distinguish between (for example) boolean false and the string 'false'.